# A C++ program that inputs two 3*3 matrice and display the sum and product of the matrices

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, matrix-multiplication

It's a c++ program that takes input for 3*3 matrices and displays the sum and product of those matrices. Now I have improved the program and it's working as expected, so is there anything that can be improved in this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//function prototypes
```

To get the input for an array.

```
void getarr(int *x);
```

To add the two matrices.

```
void addm(int *x, int *y, int *z);
```

To print an array.

```
void displaym(int *x);
```

To multiply two arrays.

```
void multm(int *x, int *y, int *z);
```

main function

```
int main() {

    //declaring arrays for matrices
    int a[3][3];
    int b[3][3];
    int c[3][3];
    int d[3][3];

    //getting input from user
    printf("\nEnter nine numbers as the values for first matrix:\n");
    getarr(a[0]);
    printf("\nThe matrix you entered is:\n");
    displaym(a[0]);
    printf("\nEnter nine numbers as the values for second matrix:\n");
    getarr(b[0]);
    printf("\nThe matrix you entered is:\n");
    displaym(b[0]);
    
    //calling function for addition
    addm(a[0], b[0], c[0]);

    //calling function for multiplication
    multm(a[0], b[0], d[0]);

    //printing the matrices
    printf("\nThe sum of the matrices is:\n");
    displaym(c[0]);
    printf("\nThe product of the matrices is:\n");
    displaym(d[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

definition of functions

```
void getarr(int *x) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        printf("%d:", j);
        scanf("%d", x);
        x++;
    }
}

void addm(int *x, int *y, int *z) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        *z = *x + *y;
        z++;
        x++;
        y++;
    }
}

void multm(int *x, int *y, int *z) {
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++, z++) {
        *z = (*x++)*(*y)+(*x++)**(y + 3)+(*x)**(y + 6);
        x -= 2, y += 1;
    }
    x += 3, y -= 3;
    }
}

void displaym(int *x) {
    printf("\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("%d  ", *x++);
        if (i == 2 || i == 5)
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of environment is this program running within?  A message like `RUN FAILED` is not familiar.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? My suspicion would be something in `multm` going outside the bounds of the arrays

Comment: `d` is uninitialised in `main`

Comment: sigesgv means segmentation fault which means you are probably trying to access some uniinitalized pointer data

Comment: I am using Netbeans to run this program.

Comment: The statement `(*x++)*(*y)+(*x++)*(*y+3)+(*x)*(*y+6)` probably has undefined behavior. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior

Comment: `d` is still not initialised to a valid array. `multm` also modifies the global variable meaning you wont be able to call it more than once

Comment: `multm` is (a) wrong and (b) atrociuos. Is there a requirement for you to write it this way? Use indices please. By the way, a `[9]` array is not the same as a `[3][3]` array, the program has undefined behaviour. It also looks like a C program. C and C++ are different languages. C++ has a different set of native idioms.

Comment: I wanted to do all the calculations using the pointers.

Comment: Plesae note the warning and the different outcomes [here](https://godbolt.org/z/qbercP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is a common error for uninitialized pointers. You declared `int * d;` earlier in the program but you never give it a memory that `d` should point to. And you need to initialize that memory.

You can add the following line inside `main` but before any use of `d`,

```
d = new int[9];
memset(d, 0, 9);
```

Comment: you are right, in this case, d is supposed to be an array. I will update